# Binned Barplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, binning

I want to make a barplot with binned data on the x axis and a corresponding probability on the y axis.
Each bin should contain 100 observations.
Here's a snapshot of my working data frame:

`head(covs)
  y Intercept        slope      temp heatload cti
1 0         1 1.175494e-38 -7.106242       76 100
2 0         1 4.935794e-01 -7.100835      139  11
3 1         1 3.021236e-01 -7.097794      126  12
4 1         1 1.175494e-38 -7.097927       75  98
5 0         1 1.175494e-38 -7.098462       76  98
6 0         1 1.175494e-38 -6.363284       76 100`

And initial execution:

```
slopes <- as.matrix(covs$slope)
binned.slopes=cut2(slopes, m=100)
heights <- tapply(covs$y,binned.slopes,mean)
barplot(heights, ylim=c(0,1),
    ylab="Probability of permafrost",
    xlab="Slope",     
    col="lightgrey")
```

With the following result:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. What would be a better way to represent the x-axis without sacrificing explanatory power?  The problem is that the intervals are all different lengths, given that bins are determined by observation count.
2. Is there a better way to do this in ggplot2?

Comment: Have you seen `hist`?

Comment: Yeah...I'll look into it

Comment: correspondingly `geom_histogram` in `ggplot2` land

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try plotting on a continuous axis and drawing the rectangles individually:

```
## Generate some sample data
covs <- data.frame(slope=rnorm(4242), y=sample(0:1, 4242, replace=TRUE))

## Sort it by slope (x-values)
covs <- covs[order(covs$slope), ]

## Set up the plot with a continuous x-axis
plot(
    x=covs$slope, 
    y=covs$y, 
    type='n',
    xlab='Slope',
    ylab='Probability of permafrost'
)

## Split the data into bins, and plot each rectangle individually
for (bin in split(covs, ceiling(seq(nrow(covs))/100))) {
    with(bin, rect(min(slope), 0, max(slope), mean(y), col='lightgrey'))
}
rm(bin)
```